# How to install Neo4j-etl-cli tool

Tags: mysql, neo4j, etl

I am using Neo4j 3.3.3 Desktop version.

I have tried the standard procedures to install the ETL tool given in:

> https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl/#neo4j-etl-cli

But couldn't install it.

I couldn't find the below json file path:

> $DESKTOP/Application/graphApps.json

But I tried to copy the following lines in 

`[
    {
        "appId": "neo4j-etl-ui",
        "appName": "ETL App",
        "packageUrl": "https://neo.jfrog.io/neo/api/npm/npm/neo4j-etl-ui"
    }
]`

> \Neo4j Desktop\Application\graphApps\neo4j-browser\package.json

Also I did download and copy the jar file :

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar

to

> \installation-3.3.3\lib

--After doing the following two steps when i opened my Neo4j Browser i didnt find any change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to add the driver into a specific file using the ui. You will select it after you started the etl tool. The path is \AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application add the graphApps.json here. After this you can go to a project and add the ETL App to your applications. There is a button to the right of your Neo4j Browser where you can select the ETL App.

Comment: Hi @Yoshi Thank you for the reply.
can you be a little more specific. I Couldnt start the etl tool, i am getting this error : The system cannot find the file specified,
Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.etl.NeoIntegrationCli

Comment: You are trying to run the etl tool in the command line right?

Comment: I had the same problem and i already posted the issue https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl/issues/8 . My answer is for the UI in neo4j desktop. can you see the app now?

Comment: Follow the steps of my answer and you should be able to see the ETL-App displayed in neo4j Desktop. Then you can just click on it and use the tool. You dont have to use the command tool if you are using the UI anyway. So dont mind getting an error there! Just copy your graphApps.json to the path i stated in my answer and you can use the etl-app in neo4j desktop.

Comment: No I still cannot see the app. I see you have came across similar problem and you posted it in github but there werent any solution for it that has been mentioned in github.

Comment: Go into a project and beside your neo4j browser you should be able to add an app

Comment: And yes there is no solution for this problem yet. But I am able to start the etl-app in neo4j desktop

Comment: Thank you very much @Yoshi
Finally i am able to see it.

Comment: Thats great! No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Neo4j desktop 1.0.22
I was struggling to install the ETL UI tool, I tried @Yoshi 's path for the graphApps.json but didn't work.

After a bit of exploring I finally found the right path for this application's version.
The path on windows is actually: 
%USER/.Neo4jDesktop/graphApps.json
It should NOT be placed under %USER/AppData/Roaming/Neo4j/Application

At least for this version of the software